# Jboss as 7.1 throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while using hibernate 4.3.8

Tags: java, jboss7.x, jpa-2.0, hibernate-4.x

i am new to hibernate, and trying to use for my project, i am using hibernate 4.3.8-Final and when i deployed to Jboss as 7.1 i am getting below error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform from [Module "org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate:4" from lo
cal module loader @699774b8 (roots: D:\Softwares\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules)]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
```

i have followed below jboss configuration for using newer hibernate version

> https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-ReplacingthecurrentHibernate4.0.xjarswithanewerversion

but i am getting above exception, after having those configuration in joboss.

when i looked into the Jboss jpa configuation , i see jboss.api been loaded instead of hibernate.

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.jboss.as.jpa">
    <properties>
        <property name="jboss.api" value="private"/>
    </properties>

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar"/>
        <!-- Insert resources here -->
    </resources>
```

so my question is how to load hibernate jpa before jboss jpa, or is there any other alternative to solve this issue.

Comment: FYI : Hibernate 4.3.8 final supports JPA 2.1 (introduced since Hibernate 4.3.0 final was [released](http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/HibernateORM430FinalRelease) (on December 16, 2013))

Comment: Please add your jboss-deployment-structure.xml

Comment: What jvm version do you use with jboss? 1.5?!

Comment: using java 1.7 version

Comment: @MartinBaumgartner i dont have the file.. all i have is jboss-web.xml

Answer (score 0):

- Jboss 7.1.1 has bundled Hibernate 4.0.1.
- Wildfy 8.2 provides 4.3.7.

Practically this means, that  if you want to rely to the "provided" Hibernate-JPA library your application's "hibernate" requirements  must conform to the above. You have however the option to create a war, jar or ear application providing your preferred version of Hibernate-JPA in them.

My advice is try Wildfly, it's  much better that 7.1.x and there are no big changes between Hibernate 4.3.7 and 4.3.8

Personally I would avoid to "patch" the application server, unless ther's  a critical issue that affects my apps.

For further assistance you must provide your Maven pom file.

Comment: i cant try different server, since i am using cloud platform which uses jboss 7.1 server, the link which i have provided has explained how to use hibernate 4 with jboss 7.1, but i have done some mistake which doesnt working for me now.

Comment: The JPA 2.1 specification added some of the more exotic features, like mapping converters, stored procedure support, and unsynchronized persistence contexts for improved conversational operations. It also added the ability to create entity graphs and pass them to queries, amounting to what are commonly known as fetch groupconstraints on the returned object set.

Comment: Ignore the previous comment. I don't use native Hibernate, I only use JPA. Hibernate 4.0.x conforms to JPA 2.0 and Hibernate 4.3.x to JPA 2.1.  JPA 2.1 specification added features such as, mapping converters, stored procedure support, and unsynchronized persistence contexts. My applications for the moment are very much JPA 2.0 compliant. Maybe that's your case. Why don't you try the provided JPA 2.0 support? To try this, that will involve only minimal changes to your maven pom. Change the scope of anything Hibernate/JPA related from compile scope to provided scope.